# Migrating from TableServiceContext to CloudTable

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am migrating my Azure code from using TableServiceContext to CloudTable, due to the following warning (migrating to the latest Azure SDK from an older version)

**'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DataServices.TableServiceEntity' is obsolete: 'Support for accessing Windows Azure Tables via WCF Data Services is now obsolete. It's recommended that you use the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table namespace for working with tables.'**

One of the problems is that in TableServiceContext I used the following

```
_tableServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
_tableServiceContext.SaveChangesDefaultOptions =      SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate;
_tableServiceContext.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;
_tableServiceContext.Format.UseAtom();
_tableServiceContext.WritingEntity += JobRepository_WritingEntity;
```

Whats the equivalent in the new SDK?

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried? with the errors etc that you are getting from it...

Comment: There is actually nothing to share here, I have shared everything that is required.

Answer (score 1):

These properties are specific to the behavior of the ServiceContext, and do not apply to using the CloudTable class.